# Php interval is stoped after sometime

Tags: php, server, intervals

I have a problem in my php server.
I found that, my php interval is stopped for some reason.
Here is the code.

main.php

```html
<?php
ignore_user_abort();
set_time_limit(0);
$interval=1;
$j=1;
upload_content("<\nStart: ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+8 hours"))."\r\n");
do{
    $run = include 'config.php';
    if(!$run) {
        upload_content("\n"."Cycle: ".$j."\t|End Onservice update \t|".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+8 hours"))."\r");
        die('no no');
    }
    if(date("s") == "30"||date("s") == "00"){
        require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/php/service/test.php';
        
        if($update_success == TRUE){
            $content = "\n"."Cycle: ".$j."\t|Update Success  \t|".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+8 hours"))."\r";
            upload_content($content);
            $j+=1;
        } else {
            $content = "\n"."Cycle: ".$j."\t|Update Fail!! \t|".date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime("+8 hours"))."\r";
            upload_content($content);
            $j+=1;
        }
        $interval = 28;
    }
    upload_content("Interval: ".$interval."\n");
    if(sleep($interval)){
        upload_content("End Interval\n");
    }
    $interval = 1;
}while(true);


function upload_content($content){
    $file = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/record/record_Onservice.txt';
    $fp = @fopen($file, "a+");
    fwrite($fp,$content);
    fclose($fp);
}

?>
```

The code is used to update information for every half a minute. In actual function, may few second to update but this time I just use test.php for testing. In order to make sure that there are no accumulative delay, I would keep checking the second in minute.

config.php

```html
<?php
return 1;
?>
```

test.php

```html
<?php
$update_success = TRUE;
?>
```

record_Onservice.txt (Result)

```html
Cycle: 1 |Update Success   |2017-10-30 13:35:00
Interval: 28
Interval: 1
Interval: 1

Cycle: 2 |Update Success   |2017-10-30 13:35:30
Interval: 28
Interval: 1
Interval: 1

Cycle: 3 |Update Success   |2017-10-30 13:36:00
Interval: 28
Interval: 1
Interval: 1

Cycle: 4 |Update Success   |2017-10-30 13:36:30
Interval: 28
End Interval
Interval: 1
Interval: 1
Interval: 1
Interval: 1
Interval: 1
Interval: 1
```

Comment: even with a time-out of infinity some hosts will not allow scripts to run for ever

Comment: by the looks of it you should *really* use a db not a flat file

Comment: what is your php.ini value of ignore_user_abort? Are you closing the shell after you started the script?